# Get HTTP error code in Spring MVC Error handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling

I build the following little Error Handler inside a spring mvc application:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Error Handler{
    @ExceptionHandler(value={Throwable.class})
    public ModelAndView handleException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Throwable t){
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        // ... some more stuff and output
    }
}
```

My problem now is, that a spring based error handling does not set the HTTP error code correct. My first attempt was a `web.xml` based solution that:

- positiv: set the HTTP status codes correct
- negative: only handeled the error codes I provided

My new solution (see above) is better suited for my purpose. But I now must find a solution in order to set the http status codes.
I took a closer look at the `Throwable` and it seems that it provides the correct errors in the correct situations:

- on a 404 (not found) it gives me a `org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /test`
- on a 405 (method not allowed) it gives me a `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported`
- on a 500 (internal server error) it gives me a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

But how can I now find the correct http status codes? Can I read them in the `HttpServletRequest` or the `HttpServletResponse`?
Because when I can get them from somewhere, I coud set it with `response.setStatus(...)`.

But the only thing I found on stackoverflow was this:

```
Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
```

And this is always `null` in my current spring based solution. (in my `web.xml` solution it was possible to read out the status code on this way. But now not my tomcat throws the error. Now spring takes care of the error way earlier in the pipe.)

So how can I get the correct http status code in the correct situation?

thanks for any help :)

Comment: did you checked @Autowired private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

Answer (score 0):

Just like you set status code using `response.setStatus(status)` you can get response's status with: `int status = response.getStatus()`

The only requirement to do so is using Servlet 3.0.

Comment: But currently all error pages have a 200. so woudn't I get this when I use `getStatus()`? ... And besides that, I have no method `getStatus()`. Do you mean 3.0-alpha on `javax.servlet`?

Comment: If you use Servlet in version 3.0 at least you can invoke method `getStatus()` on `HttpServletResponse` object. Status 200 is default status for response and when exception is being thrown it does not affect response object.

Comment: no `getStatus()` on the 3.0 `javax.servlet:servlet-api`. But from my understanding of your answer, it would not help me. So I wonder why I can not use `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code")` anymore. Why is this not avaible in my new spring based solution, but in the old way over the web.xml it was? and is there an equivalent?